# How to take off objects from map when using Q-learning with OpenAI-Gym in Python

Tags: python, openai-gym, q-learning

I'm trying to learn how to use Q-learning with OpenAI-Gym in Python, and I modified existing gym 'FrozenLake-v0' to make an example, where agent is going through the map of labirynth and picks up apples - there is a reward for every picked apple. And picked apple should disappear from map, so it wouldn't be picked endlessly. What I'm trying to ask, is how to make that work in theory - that "picking" and taking off objects from map? Should I decrease reward in q-table value for that place when I get an apple? What is most proper solution for that problem?

Comment: How are you representing your states?

Comment: Well, first I have probability, then index to next state, reward and done, for eg:

[(0.3, 21, 0.0, False)]

Nevertheless, I'm quite new in this and because I'm not sure if I answered properly to your question, this is link to the gym I'm using: https://github.com/openai/gym/blob/master/gym/envs/toy_text/frozen_lake.py

Comment: You could modify the state matrix by removing the character representing an apple after it has been picked and replace it with a normal tile.